# Javascript RegExp - it include space and brackets around

Tags: javascript, regex

Bit of a noob to regexp

Please check out [my attempt](https://regex101.com/r/nQ3uR0/5).

I want to isolate numbers that do not have hyphen or other characters around them apart from brackets - and then place quotes around these digits

so far I have - `[^a-z-0-9](\d+)[^0-9-a-z]`

match group of digits - that does not start or end with numbers or charachters

It is currently matching (1, 2) instead of say 1 and 2

Test

```
(0-hyphen-number) OR
(123 no hyphen) OR
(no hyphen 2) OR
(no 3 hyphen) OR
(no -4- hyphen) OR
(no -5 hyphen) OR
(no 6- hyphen) OR
(blah 0987 hyp1hen) OR
(blah -4321 hyp-2hen) OR
(blah -1234- hyp3-hen)
```

Expected ouput :)

```
(0-hyphen-number) OR
("123" no hyphen) OR
(no hyphen "2") OR
(no "3" hyphen) OR
(no -4- hycphen) OR
(no -5 hyphden) OR
(no 6- hyphen) OR
(blah "0987" hyp1hen) OR
(blah -4321 hyp-2hen) OR
(blah -1234- hyp3-hen)
```

Comment: What's expected output exactly?

Comment: What's the problem? The regex seems to match what you want.

Comment: Remember, in JS there are no lookbehind assertions. So, the capture group and the current regex should be all you need.

Comment: Just when you think you've got it working, bang `[^a-z-0-9]` matches an entire library of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is close enough. You should however put `-` either at end or at beginning or character class.

You should capture all groups and replace them as follows.

**Regex:** `([^a-z0-9-])(\d+)([^0-9a-z-])`

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `$1"$2"$3`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ3uR0/6)**

Comment: Many thanks - yeah I had the hypen escaped before :) just enclosing and using the $1 - $3 worked

Comment: Ahh there is another issue with this - it is skipping consecutive numbers - https://regex101.com/r/pO4mO1/2

Answer (score 1):

`do not have hyphen or other characters around them apart from brackets`

You should take note that your original regex `[^a-z-0-9](\d+)[^0-9-a-z]`
matches any punctuation around the digits.

So, `,888+` and `,888]` or `*888}` will match.

But what you're probably looking for is something like this

`(?:^|[\s()])(\d+)(?:[\s()]|$)`

which only allows whitespace boundary or parenth's boundary.

Change `[\s()]` to `[\s(]` or `[\s}]` to suite your needs.

---

Modification:  To get possibly whitespace separated numbers as well.
https://regex101.com/r/pO4mO1/3

`(?:^|[\s()])(\d+(?:\s*\d)*)(?:[\s()]|$)`

Expanded

```
 (?:
      ^ 
   |  [\s()] 
 )
 (                             # (1 start)
      \d+ 
      (?: \s* \d )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?:
      [\s()] 
   |  $ 
 )
```

Comment: another issue with this - it is skipping consecutive numbers https://regex101.com/r/pO4mO1/2

Answer (score 0):

By the time I loaded Regex101, it already had this working regex: `[^a-z-0-9](\d+)[^0-9-a-z]`

FYI (for everyone confused), in earlier revisions of the post, the regex was `^a-z-0-9[^0-9-a-z]`. Another user edited the post to reflect what they saw in the demo.